# Swift: iOS Animation stops after viewing the MessageController (message page of iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, message

I am running an animation after the user presses a logo.
This is the animation:

```
func rightRotateView(targetView: UIView, duration: Double = 5) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear] , animations: {
        targetView.transform = targetView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi * 5)

    }) { finished in
       // self.rightRotateView(targetView: targetView)
    }
}
```

After 3 seconds of a long press (in this time the animation should still run), I am presenting the message controller for the user:

```
 if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true {
        print(self.urgentNumber)
        let recipients:[String] = ["\(self.urgentNumber as! String)"]
        self.messageController.messageComposeDelegate  = self as? MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
        self.messageController.recipients = recipients
        self.messageController.body = "Hey,\nmy longitude: \(self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude) \nmy latitude: \(self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"

        self.present(self.messageController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    } else {
        //handle text messaging not available

    }
```

when I press the cancel button in the message control, I am returning to the animation page, but the animation stops working. 
I tried to rerun the animation after the present, and in the

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {

}
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, just rerun the same animation in the completion, (you can use CABasicAnimation or simply UIView.animate):

```
func rightRotateView(targetView: UIView, duration: Double = 5) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear] , animations: {
        targetView.transform = targetView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi * 5)

    }) { finished in
        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"transform.rotation")
        anim.fromValue = 0.000
        anim.toValue = 360.0
        anim.speed = 0.001
        anim.repeatCount = .infinity
        targetView.layer.add(anim, forKey: "transform.rotation")
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this, and saw that the animation just restarted when I added this implementation. If the animation is in the middle, it will restart, giving a choppy effect. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score -1):

Use for this CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")

Comment: a more detailed answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: More context on this would be really helpful - I'm having a similar issue. Thanks!